# Laravel stream a video from own hard drive

Tags: html, laravel-5, video-streaming

I am building an app to organaize, manage and play a family film collection of about 700 films with Laravel5 that should be capable to play the films in format MP4.

In my HTML code I have the following code:

```
<video width="100%" height="360" controls>
    <source src="http://my-domain.com/films/xanadu.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

However, I can't upload 700 films to a hosting space (not to mention the copyright problems). So I decided to store locally and play films from my hard drive. So, I have created a directory under public and add there a film, like this:

```
my-app
    public
        films
            xanadu.mp4
```

and changed the code to

```
<video width="100%" height="360" controls>
    <source src="{{ asset('films/xanadu.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Inspecting the element I get the right address:

```
http://family-film.test/films/xanadu.mp4
```

But I get the error:

**No video with supported format and MIME type found.**

So, I wonder if there is any error in my code or it is just technically ipossible to stream a video from the own hard drive using the HTML5 video tag

Comment: Why don't you use something made for that purpose like PLEX? To answer your question... how is your computer connected to "family-film.test"? Since the URL doesn't exist I'd say "not at all"?

Comment: I am using Laragon which build for me a virtual address locally (instead localhost). The app is still in development

Comment: By the way, I did not know PLESK, however I want to build my own app in order to learn LARAVEL

Answer (score 0):

You can try many browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge,...) to avoid browser issue.
If all of them don't work, you can add this to your `.htaccess`:

`AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p`